# Code working on all browsers but not working on Emulator "phonegap"

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I've creating a cross platform app using phonegab, jquery mobile 
developing in Eclipse IDE 
I'm sending a request to a remote server & getting a list of JSON 
objects 
I save them as records in a database 
then I render those records to be viewed in a table on the Index page 
It's working fine when I tried it on all browsers IE, Chrome, Firefox, 
safari 
but when I tried to test it on the Android emulator nothing is working 
at all 
any ideas ??

Answer (score 0):

Android emulator sometimes does not connect to NET automatically, we need to  forcefully  connect it. If the reason is not of NET connection then try to open database (create if not exist).